# Выбор лицензии для платного ПО

Tags: php, git

Всем привет!)
Разрабатываю веб-скрипт на PHP, для продажи.

Хочу выдавать покупателям доступ к проекту в гитлабе и не знаю какую лицензию выбрать.

Подскажите, есть ли лицензия запрещающая перепродажу и распространение другим людям ПО?

Comment: А почему просто так и не написать? Вы не объязаны выбирать готовую лицензию - можно написать все, что не противоречит законодательству. Если же не уверены по поводу законодательства, добавьте оговорку вида "если это не противоречит законодательству".

А лучше, проконсультируйтесь с юристом.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал. Я в этом деле "ламер")

Comment: А я за открытое ПО. А котов в мешке с ужасным кодом и так хватает. П.С не про ваш код речь сейчас в целом в коммерческой разработке

Comment: @Naumov, Некоторым разработчикам ведь нужны хоть какие-то деньги)
Другое дело если они после того как N-ую сумму денег насобирают иии... конец.

Comment: @KobaltMR вы можете поддерживать opensorce проэкты за деньги, т.е. у вас есть проэкт с открытым исходным кодом, есть люди которым всё нравиться и код и его работа, но они хотели бы больше, они обращаються к вам за поддержкой мол а мы тебе заплатим вот столько то столько то ты реализуй... Вот такая схема, а покупать какой то скрипт где то там ни кто нибудет...

Comment: Вообще можете показать кусок вашего кода хотелось бы провести кодревью, вы как рас токи сможете решить что вам нужно да и мнение сообщества разработчиков тоже важно.

Comment: @Naumov, я не просто скрипт продаю. Я так-же оказываю тех. поддержку по нему, найденные баги исправляю обычно на след. день.
Вообще в репозитории надобность появилась, ибо появились люди которые тоже бы хотели мне помочь, и легче будет если они будут пуллы посылать в реп, а не мне скидывать файлы.

А вообще, я сейчас занимаюсь одним проектом открытым, вот он как раз и нацелен на то что-бы сообщество его оценило и т.д.

Comment: Ссылку то можно?

Comment: @Naumov, Насчёт открытого: я только недавно начал писать, так что пока всё что есть https://gitlab.com/WhileTeam/MinePanel/tree/master

P.S. Есть чутка смешивание ООП и процедурки.

Comment: Случаем не bitrix взят за основу вам надо учиться ещё и учиться php пойти в офис поработать набраться опыта.

Comment: @Naumov, таки о битрексе ничего не знаю, так что нет. А про учёбу - это да. Вообще оценку этого кода можно? (Заранее спасибо)

Comment: оформил как ответом

Answer (score 1):

Выбор лицензии во многом зависит от страны распространения.

Большинство международных лицензий в РФ не имеют юридической силы. Их стараются придерживаться в основном из уважения к разработчикам и возможности выхода на международный рынок.

Поэтому для выбора нужно знать в какой стране будет распространяться. И в любом случае лицензия будет коммерческой.

Желательно для каждой страны консультироваться с "местными" юристами. Когда на юристов нет денег, за основу берут близкий по структуре продукт и перерабатывают его договор.

Answer (score 0):

https://gitlab.com/WhileTeam/MinePanel/blob/master/classes/database.class.php
глобальные переменные зло, избавиться надо от них проинициализировать лучше конфиг прямо в конструкторе.

```
        if ((!isset($session[0]) or !isset($session[1]))
        or (empty($session[0]) or empty($session[1]))) {
            $this->is_auth = false;
            unset($_SESSION['auth']);
            return;
        }
```

эта конструкция вообще работает?
к стати есть разница между `or` и `||`.
Плюс `empty` это синоним `!isset && is_null()` т.е. `isset` тут лишний.

`global $db;` опять глобальные

```
<?php
$mpage['title'] = 'Главная страница';

$users_count = $db->fetch("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `mpk_users`")['COUNT(`id`)'];
$last_version = '1.0';

ob_start();
include_once STYLE . '/pages/main.html';
$mpage['content'] = ob_get_clean();
```

`$db` не понятно от куда появилось.
Документации вообще нет.

```
if (isset($_GET['login']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $login = @$_POST['login']; // нельзя так
    $passw = @$_POST['password']; 

    if (empty($login) or empty($passw)) {
        alert('Введите логин/пароль!', 0, 0, 0);
    }
    $passw = md5(md5($passw));
    $userRow = $db->fetch("SELECT * FROM `mpk_users` WHERE `login` = '{$login}'"); // sql inj уязвимость
```

тут @ точно не к чему:
 `if (empty(@$userRow['login'])){`

```
   if ($userRow['password'] != $passw) {
            alert('Неверный логин/пароль!', 0, 0, 0);
        }
```

Это запросом решаеться на этапе выборки.

`exit(header('Location: index.php'));` - ну и зачем тут `exit()` location всё равно уйдёт на другую страницу.

Comment: в index.php подключается system.php а в нём уже конфиг, класс с БД, и другие классы. Классы инициализируются. Далее в индексе загружается страница и проблем с переменными типа $db и $user не будет,